# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized when using XML-RPC PHP client and server

Tags: remote-desktop, browser, php, webserver, https

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document
you requested.  Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad 
password), or your browser does not understand how to supply the 
credentials required. 

Fault Code: 5, Reason: Didn't receive 200 OK from remote server. 
(HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized)
```

I am trying to access an API server through its IP address via PHP XML-RPC protocol. Why is the server giving this error?

Comment: What API? What are you trying to do?